# How do I delete all old labels using a button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create this so I can check the price of a crypto easier.
I want to store a history which it does at the moment. But I also want a way of deleting all of the old labels.
I can only delete the most recent one as I reassign a new value to the `price_label` every time I hit <kbd>CHECK BOG</kbd> button.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import webbrowser
from tkinter import *
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen
root = Tk()


url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bogged-finance/"

def check():
    url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bogged-finance/"
    page = urlopen(url)
    html = page.read().decode("utf-8")
    pattern = '<div class="priceValue___11gHJ">.*?</div>'
    match_results = re.search(pattern, html, re.IGNORECASE)
    title = match_results.group()
    title = re.sub("<.*?>", "", title) # Remove HTML tags
    global price_label
    price_label = Label(root, text = title)
    price_label.pack()




#trying to clear 
def clear():
    print("hello")
    price_label.pack_forget()


#trying to open link

def open():
    webbrowser.open('https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bogged-finance/')



button_check = Button(root, text  ="CHECK BOG", command = check)

button_clear = Button(root, text ="CLEAR", command = clear)

button_open = Button(root, text = 'Website', command = open)

button_clear.pack()
button_check.pack()
button_open.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to either store the labels in a list so that you can iterate over them later, or you can put them in a frame and then loop over all of the children of the frame, calling `destroy` on each child. Or, just leave the code as-is and loop over all of the children of `root`, and only destroy the labels.

Yet another solution is to use a single `Text` or `Listbox` widget to store all of the items, rather than use individual `Label` widgets. Both of those widgets make it pretty easy to delete their contents.